# Datetime issues on conversion. Parameterized query is not accepting the datetime value

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, parameterized-query

I have this function `ExecuteSqlParameterizedQuery` and here under is my query:

```
Queryobj.ExecuteSqlParameterizedQuery(String.Format("INSERT INTO tbladd(ID,MyDateTime,Birthday)values({0},@dta, @dtb)", m_Id, MyDateTime.ToString(), MyBirthday.ToString());
```

1. `MyDateTime` is of `DateTime` datatype.
2. `MyBirthday` is of `DateTime` datatype.

Here is my function:

```
readonly SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(PC_Software.Properties.Settings.Default.DbConnectionString);

    public void ExecuteSqlParameterizedQuery(string SQL, string measdt, string dob)
    {
        try
        {
            using (var cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                con.Open();
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();  
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dta", measdt);
                if(dob != "0DATA#")
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dtb", dob);
                }
                cmd.CommandText = SQL;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            con.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

This shows me this particular error: `the conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value. the statement has been terminated.`

I tried to find the issue but unable to understand how exactly i can do changes to my code to rectify the issue.

**Edit:**

Also i have this as my Datetime interface:

```
public interface enn
{
    DateTime MyDateTime
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

And datetime declaration is like this:

```
    DateTime? MyBirthday
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you pass the `MyBirthday` parameter to the method you are converting it to a string:

```
MyBirthday.ToString()
```

You should leave it as a `DateTime` - and the same with `MyDateTime`

you will obviously need to change your method signature to accept these values

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

> MyDateTime.Date
>
> MyBirthday.Date

```
Queryobj.ExecuteSqlParameterizedQuery(String.Format("INSERT INTO tbladd(ID,MyDateTime,Birthday)values({0},@dta, @dtb)", m_Id, MyDateTime.Date, MyBirthday.Date);
```

Comment: But `MyBirthday` is actually Null so it says that `'System.Nullable<System.DateTime>' does not contain a definition for 'Date' and no extension method 'Date' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Nullable<System.DateTime>' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Did you initialize both Dates?

Comment: Yes i did it like this `MyBirthday = System.DateTime.Now;`

Comment: Remove the Quotation mark "?" that is why you get the Nullable error (DateTime? MyBirthday) from MyBirthday property please